# C++ open jar executable while running a fullscreen application

Tags: java, c++, fullscreen

So my problem is:
I have a C++ program with the code

```
system("C:/myexecutable.jar");
```

This code is called when I press my F8 key. So, I'm running a fullscreen game, and I press F8. My Jar executable now opens fine, but it minimizes my game. All I want is that it just covers the screen.
In my java application I also have

```
MyFrame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
MyFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

So, how can I fix it?

Comment: Does setAlwaysOnTop(false) make nothing?

Comment: If I set it to false it still minimizes my game, but now if I maximize the game again my Java application no longer covers it